# Piezoelctric Ceramic Transducing Capabilties

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering, piezoelectric

Piezoelectric ceramics are able to work as transducers, outputting electrical energy when mechanical stress is inputted. However, most ceramics have high static voltage and low current and power outputs, especially PZT. This is not useful for energy harvesting, especially as power output is very minimal.

Nevertheless, what are some good piezoelectric materials that have good coupling coefficients and can be applied for energy harvesting? This is for independent research purposes. Therefore, I wish for material that is not dangerous/hazardous nor unavailable in the consumer market.

If there are no materials as such, what are some processes that can possibly amplify the effect of PZT in energy harvesting processes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All commonly-available commercial piezoelectric materials produce extremely small electrical currents in response to applied stresses which produce extremely small strains in the material.

If we model this process in terms of power flow, the power produced is similarly extremely small because it is the product of voltage (of order ~several volts) times current (of order ~several microamps). We conclude the process exhibits a very high characteristic impedance (typically of order ~10 megohms) and to obtain significant amounts of electrical power then requires very significant amounts of induced strain in the material. Since the material is ceramic, however, large strains lead to brittle fracture and this puts limits on the power output of a single PZT disc.

This leads to the idea of stacking up large numbers of individual PZT discs and wiring them together so their currents add. The stack is then driven by a mechanical system that applies cyclic high pressure/small displacement loads to the stack.

Work was done on this power generation concept in the early 1970's (either at UC Berkeley or UC San Diego) but at the time it did not yield a practical device that could successfully compete with more conventional forms of electrical power generation.